# Inserting data and sort into multidimensional vectors

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to insert data based on a given value - strBeg. I want the vectors to be sorted numerically based on this value. There are two different vectors. With my driver program shown below I would want the output to be:

```
linei[0][0] = 1  linei[0][1] = 8  refi[0][0] = 81 refi[0][1] = 88
linei[1][0] = 21 linei[1][1] = 31 refi[1][0] = 10 refi[1][1] = 20
linei[0][0] = 33 linei[0][1] = 44 refi[0][0] = 0  refi[0][1] = 11
linei[1][0] = 45 linei[1][1] = 47 refi[1][0] = 6  refi[1][1] = 8
```

As you can see the value of refBeg/refEnd does not affect the order, but must stay with it's strBeg/strEnd pair. I've posted my code below...it does not work. My current method is going to require a very large sorting function accounting for many different cases and I would like to avoid that if possible. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to implement this? I've though about combining the two vectors into one that will have 4 columns but would rather not as this will make it more confusing to understand (but am not completely opposed if it's the best/easiest option). Also there will be no overlap in linei, as in there will not be two sets of data with the same strBeg and strBeg/strEnd will not fall in between another strings start and stop points. I read through some other similar questions but couldn't quite figure out how to adapt them to my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!
NOTE: If I don't reply tonight I will in the morning. Thanks again!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void insertData(const int refBeg, const int refEnd, const int strBeg, const int strEnd, vector<vector<int> >& refi, vector<vector<int> >& linei);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<vector<int> > refi;
    vector<vector<int> > linei;

    insertData(0, 11, 33, 44, refi, linei);
    insertData(10, 20, 21, 31, refi, linei);
    insertData(6, 8, 45, 47, refi, linei);
    insertData(80, 88, 1, 8, refi, linei);


    for (int i=0; i<linei.size(); i++) {
        cout << "linei[" << i << "][0] = " << linei[i][0] << " ";
        cout << "linei[" << i << "][1] = " << linei[i][1] << " ";
        cout << "refi[" << i << "][0] = " << refi[i][0] << " ";
        cout << "refi[" << i << "][1] = " << refi[i][1] << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}



void insertData(const int refBeg, const int refEnd, const int strBeg, const int strEnd, vector<vector<int> >& refi, vector<vector<int> >& linei) {
    linei.push_back(vector<int>() );//creates a new row in linei
    refi.push_back(vector<int>() );//creates a new row in refi
    int size=(int)linei.size();

    if ((size-1) == 0) {
        linei[0].push_back(strBeg);
        linei[0].push_back(strEnd);
        refi[0].push_back(refBeg);
        refi[0].push_back(refEnd);
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            if (strBeg > linei[i][0]) {
                linei[i+1].push_back(strBeg);
                linei[i+1].push_back(strEnd);
                refi[i+1].push_back(refBeg);
                refi[i+1].push_back(refEnd);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct line_ref
{
    vector<int> linei;
    vector<int> refi;

    bool operator<(const line_ref &rhs) const { return linei[0] < rhs.linei[0]; }
};

void insertData(const int refBeg, const int refEnd, const int strBeg, const int strEnd, vector<line_ref>& line_ref_i);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    vector<line_ref> line_ref_i;
    insertData(0, 11, 33, 44, line_ref_i);
    insertData(10, 20, 21, 31, line_ref_i);
    insertData(6, 8, 45, 47, line_ref_i);
    insertData(80, 88, 1, 8, line_ref_i);

    cout << "UNSORTED\n";
    for (int i=0; i<line_ref_i.size(); i++) {
        cout << "LINEI[0] = " << line_ref_i[i].linei[0] << " ";
        cout << "LINEI[1] = " << line_ref_i[i].linei[1] << " ";
        cout << "REFI[0] = " << line_ref_i[i].refi[0] << " ";
        cout << "REFI[1] = " << line_ref_i[i].refi[1] << endl;
    }

    sort(line_ref_i.begin(), line_ref_i.end() );//, /*??*/);

    cout << "SORTED\n";
    for (int i=0; i<line_ref_i.size(); i++) {
        cout << "LINEI[0] = " << line_ref_i[i].linei[0] << " ";
        cout << "LINEI[1] = " << line_ref_i[i].linei[1] << " ";
        cout << "REFI[0] = " << line_ref_i[i].refi[0] << " ";
        cout << "REFI[1] = " << line_ref_i[i].refi[1] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void insertData(const int refBeg, const int refEnd, const int strBeg, const int strEnd, vector<line_ref>& line_ref_i) {
    line_ref_i.push_back(line_ref() );
    int size = (int)line_ref_i.size() - 1;

    line_ref_i[size].linei.push_back(strBeg);
    line_ref_i[size].linei.push_back(strEnd);
    line_ref_i[size].refi.push_back(refBeg);
    line_ref_i[size].refi.push_back(refEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of parallel vectors, why not put the related elements into a `struct`?

```
struct line_ref
{
    vector<int> linei;
    vector<int> refi;
};

vector <line_ref> line_ref_i;
```

Alternately, instead of declaring a `struct`, you could just use a `std::pair<int,int>`, if you don't mind generic names like `first` and `second` for the fields.

Comment: For storage purposes this seems like the way to go, but what about sorting them? That is my real issue. Thanks for the help so far though!

Comment: If you provide a proper `operator<()` for the `struct`, then `std::sort` will sort them for you.  So if all you need to do is compare, say `linei[0]` between two of these, then that's all `operator<()` needs to do.  Something like `bool operator<(const line_ref &rhs) const { return linei[0] < rhs.linei[0]; }`

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding that last line. Are you using operator overloading for '<' ? Also in the return linei[0] < rhs.linei[0]; where does the linei come from? I'll post my code up above to show you the work I've done. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!